# Googles Custom Search as if manually searched

Tags: java, api, google-custom-search

I want to use Googles Custom Search Api for searching for song lyrics in the web via Java.
For getting the name and artist of current song playing I use Tesseract OCR. Even if the OCR works perfectly, I often don't get any results.
But when I try it manually: open Google in the web browser and search for the same string, then it works fine. 
So now I don't really know what is the difference between the manual search engine and the api call.
Do I have to add some parameters to the Api request?

```
//The String searchString is what I am searching for, so the song name and artist 
String searchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=(myKEY)=de&cx=(myID)&q=" + searchString + "lyrics";    
String data = getData(searchUrl);

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);
String link = "";
try
{
   link = json.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).getString("link");
   URI url = new URI(link);
   System.out.println(link);            
   Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   System.out.println("No Results");
}

private static String getData(String _urlLink) throws IOException
{   
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();     
    URL url = new URL(_urlLink);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
    {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();       

}
```

Comment: Post what code are you using for performing the search.

Comment: Just updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove *=de* before *&cx* and use `+` to represent the space between words. Like this - 
 `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=(yourKEY)&cx=(yourID)&q=paradise+coldplay+lyrics`